# Jars added to an Android library are not getting referenced in the project

Tags: android, jar, android-library

I have created an Android library where I included some external jars. These jars are seen in "Referenced Libraries" under the library project. When I reference this library in my other project, it is not able to link the jars that had been added to library. It shows errors to the referenced library under the project.

It should have linked the jars which are added in library, rather, it shows an error in the project in which I have added this library. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Do both the projects lie in the same workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got your library project properly included, go to `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and check all the JARs you wish to include in your main project. This should work, if everything's in the same workspace.

Comment: I can see the list of jars in the Order and Export in my library. But do not see them in Order and Export of my project. Yes they are in the same workspace

Comment: Okay, but are all necessary libraries in your library project checked?

Answer (score 3):

Exporting jars from library project through the `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` doesn't actually work at the end: Eclipse is able to compile a dependent project, but jars do not appear in the final apk and you get a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files to your project location, probably in a lib folder. Then try to add the library.

Comment: doesn't work... It works if I add all the jars again in the project. But It will be like adding the jars twice, once in library and then in project